# How to edit docx file in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, office-interop, docx

I need to replace user's meta tags #likethis# inside a docx file for a value in database. It was fine replacing simple strings editing the byte array of file directly. But it became more complex when I needed to load a table of data. So I had to try to use this lib but its documentation it's pretty poor.

I find on this reference how to replace bookmarks by values
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/ed7278b1-1fc7-44d5-9e87-4c3e41a110cf/how-to-modify-bookmarked-fields-in-word-docx-file-from-code?forum=worddev

But there's a way to track down a string inside the text and replace it for any content (like other text, or a table or a image like a logo) ?

Comment: Mail merge automation might be helpful here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301659/how-to-automate-microsoft-word-to-perform-mail-merge-from-visual-c

Comment: Have you tried to do it using `word` macro? If you can develop macro, you can use `interop` for this

Comment: The client will provide the file via upload, he'll be able to call the metatags wherever he want and customize all the rest of the file. I think let the application treat this just changing the fields it's safer with less chance of errors in multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article states the following:

> Microsoft strongly recommends that developers find alternatives to Automation of Office if they need to develop server-side solutions. Because of the limitations to Office's design, changes to Office configuration are not enough to resolve all issues. Microsoft strongly recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more efficiently and more quickly than Automation. Before you involve Office as a server-side component in your project, consider alternatives.
>
> Most server-side Automation tasks involve document creation or editing. Office 2007 supports new Open XML file formats that let developers create, edit, read, and transform file content on the server side. These file formats use the System.IO.Package.IO namespace in the Microsoft .NET 3.x Framework to edit Office files without using the Office client applications themselves. This is the recommended and supported method for handling changes to Office files from a service.

As a workaround you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for open XML documents. Or just any third-party wrappers designed for the server-side execution (for example, Aspose).

Comment: The content on the Open XML SDK link is a little out of date (it is for v2.5), there is now a NuGet package provided by the microsoft office team to disribute the Open XML SDK (currently on v2.8.1), https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/. A better documentation link might be to [this page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/blob/master/README.md)